# How to make Android Volley requests and socket communication only via WiFi even if connected to mobile network?

Tags: android, android-volley, android-networking

I'm developing an Android application which needs to stay connected to a specific WiFi network (without internet connection) and make all Volley HTTP requests and socket communication via WiFi. The problem is when the device mobile network is enabled the requests go all to the mobile network.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager)  getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
    // Do whatever
}
```

note: you also need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

should work.

Comment: How does that force volley not to use the mobile network?

Comment: it doesn't but it checks wether youre connected via wifi when connected via wifi normally phones use wifi and turn off mobile network so tadaa the volley will only get triggerd if youre on wifi

Comment: If both connections have internet the phone will use WiFi, but in my case my WiFi network doesn't have internet, that's the problem.

Comment: referring to this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171770/how-to-force-the-http-connection-over-wi-fi-instead-of-cellular-in-android
It's not possible to do force the connection BUT you could simply turn cellular off for the request to happen over Wifi then reanable it